# How to put the UIPageControl element on top of the sliding pages within a UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

Regarding to this [tutorial by AppCoda about how to implement a app with UIPageViewController](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) I'd like to use a custom page control element on top of the pages instead of at the bottom.

When I just put a page control element on top of the single views which will be displayed, the logical result is that the control elements scrolls with the page view away from the screen.

How is it possible to put the control element on top of the views so the page views are full screen (like with an image) so the user can see the views underneath the fixed control element?

I attached an example screenshot - credits to [AppCoda and Path](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/):

[image]

Answer (score 51, accepted):

After further investigation and searching [I found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19140401/66414), also on stackoverflow.

The key is the following message to send to a custom `UIPageControl` element:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.pageControl];
```

[The AppCoda tutorial is the foundation for this solution](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/):

Add a `UIPageControl` element on top of the `RootViewController` - the view controller with the arrow.

Create a related `IBOutlet` element in your `ViewController.m`.

In the `viewDidLoad` method you should then add the following code as the last method you call after adding all subviews.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.pageControl];
```

To assign the current page based on the pageIndex of the current content view you can add the following to the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` methods:

```
- (UIPageViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    // ...
    index--;
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:index];

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIPageViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    // ...
    index++;
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:index];

    // ...
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: strangely for me, setting the pageControl page before incrementing/decrementing the index worked. The viewController that I was getting from the method was that of the **new view controller and not the one before transition**.

Comment: That's not strange at all; it's expected. Those methods are called on the *current* view controller to determine what comes up next.

Comment: @sn3ek How to create a related IBOutlet element.

Comment: @elavarasan which element? the `self.pageControl` is for example an IBOutlet to the Page Control element on the view...

Comment: Handling `pageControl` in the datasource methods shouldn't really be recommended. As a datasouce, the only thing you should do is return the data requested (and avoid other logic) - you have no control on when these methods will be called - that's up to the implementation. For example, after a scroll you _may_ observe the PageViewController 'prefetching' the next neighbouring page ahead of time. This totally messes with any checky logic you might sneak in (and probably explains why @Gokul gets a different result to @sn3ek). (Better: use the delegate instead)

Answer (score 55):

I didn't have the rep to comment on the answer that originated this, but I really like it. I improved the code and converted it to swift for the below subclass of UIPageViewController:

```
class UIPageViewControllerWithOverlayIndicator: UIPageViewController {
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        for subView in self.view.subviews as! [UIView] {
            if subView is UIScrollView {
                subView.frame = self.view.bounds
            } else if subView is UIPageControl {
                self.view.bringSubviewToFront(subView)
            }
        }
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Clean and it works well. No need to maintain anything, just make your page view controller an instance of this class in storyboard, or make your custom page view controller class inherit from this class instead.

Comment: when i put this for loop in ViewDidLoad I can find the scrollView but not the UIPageControl view. am I missing something ?

Comment: @Hakim perhaps the controller is missing the UIPageViewController type? It's hard to say without an example of the exact situation.

Comment: I'm gonna bookmark this just for how versatile and useful this is. Thankx  so much!!

Answer (score 27):

sn3ek Your answer got me most of the way there.  I didn't set the current page using the `viewControllerCreation` methods though.

I made my `ViewController also` the delegate of the `UIPageViewController`.  Then I set the `PageControl`'s `CurrentPage` in that method.  Using the `pageIndex` maintained I'm the `ContentViewController` mention in the original article.

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{
  APPChildViewController *currentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers[0];
  [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:currentViewController.pageIndex];
}
```

don't forget to add this to `viewDidLoad`

```
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
```

To follow up on PropellerHead's comment the interface for the `ViewController` will have the form

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: Just to be clear. The delegate of UIPageViewController is UIPageViewControllerDelegate, so the interface of your ViewController will look something like this: 
```@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>```

Answer (score 3):

The same effect can be achieved simply by subclassing UIPageViewController and overriding viewDidLayoutSubviews as follows:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    UIView* v = self.view;
    NSArray* subviews = v.subviews;
    if( [subviews count] == 2 ) {
        UIScrollView* sv = nil;
        UIPageControl* pc = nil;
        for( UIView* t in subviews ) {
            if( [t isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]] ) {
                sv = (UIScrollView*)t;
            } else if( [t isKindOfClass:[UIPageControl class]] ) {
                pc = (UIPageControl*)t;
            }
        }
        if( sv != nil && pc != nil ) {
            // expand scroll view to fit entire view
            sv.frame = v.bounds;
            // put page control in front
            [v bringSubviewToFront:pc];
        }
    }
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
}
```

Then there is no need to maintain a seperate UIPageControl and such.

Comment: I actually liked this answer. It worked well. Until I put on an iPhone 4S running iOS 7.1. At which point it went infinite. Not sure why, but beware.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement a custom `UIPageControl` and add it to the view. As others have mentioned, `view.bringSubviewToFront(pageControl)` must be called.

I have an [example](http://samwize.com/2016/03/08/using-uipageviewcontroller-with-custom-uipagecontrol/) of a view controller with all the code on setting up a custom `UIPageControl` (in storyboard) with `UIPageViewController`

There are 2 methods which you need to implement to set the current page indicator.

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionToViewControllers pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
    pendingIndex = pages.indexOf(pendingViewControllers.first!)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if completed {
        currentIndex = pendingIndex
        if let index = currentIndex {
            pageControl.currentPage = index
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a RxSwift/RxCocoa answer I put together after looking at the other replies.

```
let pages = Variable<[UIViewController]>([])
let currentPageIndex = Variable<Int>(0)
let pendingPageIndex = Variable<(Int, Bool)>(0, false)

let db = DisposeBag()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pendingPageIndex
        .asDriver()
        .filter { $0.1 }
        .map { $0.0 }
        .drive(currentPageIndex)
        .addDisposableTo(db)

    currentPageIndex.asDriver()
        .drive(pageControl.rx.currentPage)
        .addDisposableTo(db)
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
    if let index = pages.value.index(of: pendingViewControllers.first!) {
        pendingPageIndex.value = (index, false)
    }
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    pendingPageIndex.value = (pendingPageIndex.value.0, completed)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Swifty 2 answer very much based on @zerotool's answer above. Just subclass UIPageViewController and then add this override to find the scrollview and resize it. Then grab the page control and move it to the top of everything else. You also need to set the page controls background color to clear. Those last two lines could go in your app delegate.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    var sv:UIScrollView?
    var pc:UIPageControl?

    for v in self.view.subviews{

        if v.isKindOfClass(UIScrollView) {

            sv = v as? UIScrollView

        }else if v.isKindOfClass(UIPageControl) {

            pc = v as? UIPageControl
        }
    }

    if let newSv = sv {

        newSv.frame = self.view.bounds
    }

    if let newPc = pc {

        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(newPc)
    }
}

let pageControlAppearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
pageControlAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

btw - I'm not noticing any infinite loops, as mentioned above.