# Change dots of UIPageControl from a ChildViewController in a ParentViewController - swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, uipagecontrol

I am trying to change the dots in a ParentViewController in function of which ChildViewController appears but I didn't find how to do it. (in swift)
Any idea ?

Here is a gif to give you a better idea :) http://gfycat.com/WarmUglyAppaloosa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution in this post which has a different goal but work in my case too ! https://stackoverflow.com/a/21048603/5164509

Comment: For posterity, could you include the relevant parts of the other answer which you found useful in your answer? That way, if the answer gets deleted, changes, etc., your answer won't be rendered useless. Many thanks.