# Path App Style Buttons on UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am working on an app and using UIPageViewController to run the intro screens in the app, followed this tutorial to get this working:

http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

I need to add 2 buttons to the bottom of the screen, under the dots, much the same way as they are added in the path app, the image is here, courtesy appcoda:

[image: sample image]

Can someone kindly share some pointers on how buttons can be placed on top of the uipageviewcontroller.

Comment: please check out this StackOverflow question and its answers and links, I think it's what you have been looking for. (placing buttons on top of the ui page controller) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045630/how-to-put-the-uipagecontrol-element-on-top-of-the-sliding-pages-within-a-uipage

Comment: Thank you, will try the solution suggested on the SO link.