# Is there any way to make the pages bottom bar transparent in iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7

There is one thing that is troubling me about the iOS7 bottom bar where the page dots appear whenever you use a PageViewController.

The thing is: it seems that this bar cannot be completely transparent in such a way that I can put viewable content 'behind' it, while having the page dots. I believe I tried every possible combination, from setting the bar color's to clear, changing the barTintColor...without any feasible result.

So here is my question: is there any legal way to make this dot bar completely transparent with the page dots appearing at the same time? That is, having only the page dots with a transparent bar?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17779735/931277

Comment: Thank you @dokkaebi, that post was the solution to my problem. I didn't see it during my searching.