# Why UIPageController on clear color returns black?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I want to change my UIPageController background color and do the next:

```
let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

but it returns me black color. How can I make it transparent?

Comment: Please check this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651309/how-to-make-uipageviewcontroller-background-translucent

Comment: As i had also asked the same question for tvOS app and the answer working perfectly. check out this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235857/change-background-color-for-page-control

Comment: UIPageControl is different class than UIPageViewController. You should change pageVC.view.backgroundColor. Did you mean on the back color of UIPageControl or UIPageViewController view?

Comment: @Prcela how can I move page dots on Axis Y by -50? I read a lot, but I still cannot move it