# UIPageViewController: how to show the UIPageControl on top of the pages

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

By default in the UIPageViewController, the dots (UIPageControl) are shown below the UIViewController pages. Is it possible to display the pages on the whole screen, to the bottom, and the dots on top on the view?

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to put a UIPageControl in your view and then move the contained PageViewController a bit lower, so the bottom UIPageControl is hidden.

See this answer for a very similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/19140401/2085504