# How to hide the background of dots in a Page View in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am currently having issues on removing the background (the bar at the bottom of the screen) like the problem that they had exactly in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779735/how-do-i-make-the-bottom-bar-with-dots-of-a-uipageviewcontroller-translucent/19140401#19140401)

However, the solutions posted were all in Objective-c. I tried to translate it to Swift, but it didn't work.

I also tried to change "UIPageControl.appearance()" to cleancolor, but it still didn't work.

Anybody can provide some hints?

Thanks!

My code here:

```
import UIKit

class TutorialViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource{

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?
let contentImages = ["Tutorial1.png", "Tutorial2.png","Tutorial3.png"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createPageViewController()
    setupPageControl()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

    //supporting functions
private func createPageViewController() {

    let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageController") as! UIPageViewController
    pageController.dataSource = self

    if contentImages.count > 0 {
        let firstController = getItemController(0)!
        let startingViewControllers: NSArray = [firstController]
        pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    pageViewController = pageController
    addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
    pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

private func setupPageControl() {
    let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
    appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}

// MARK: - UIPageViewControllerDataSource

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let itemController = viewController as! PageItemViewController

    if itemController.itemIndex > 0 {
        return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex-1)
    }

    return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let itemController = viewController as! PageItemViewController

    if itemController.itemIndex+1 < contentImages.count {
        return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)
    }

    return nil
}

private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> PageItemViewController? {

    if itemIndex < contentImages.count {
        let pageItemController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TutorialItemController")as! PageItemViewController
        pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
        pageItemController.imageName = contentImages[itemIndex]
        return pageItemController
    }

    return nil
}

// MARK: - Page Indicator

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return contentImages.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {

    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check in the example link you have provided, i found some difference which you may help you in the implementation

**1.** // We need to cover all the control by making the frame taller (+ 37)

```
[[self.pageController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[self view] bounds].size.width, [[self view] bounds].size.height + 37)];
```

- Added extra height in the PageViewController so default page controller bottom bar is hidden

// Bring the common controls to the foreground (they were hidden since the frame is taller)

**2.**

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.pcDots];
```

The trick is put the PageControl in the foreground at bottom. put UIPageControl and set the value of it in the delegate method of UIPageController

---

If you need the full demo implementation of UIPageController you can check the tutorial here:https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/

At the end of this tutorial you will get the custom UIPageController which you want, if you want to set the page control at bottom `change the position of UIPageControl in the TutorialViewController` in storyboard

Answer (score 3):

Try removing this method

```
func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
return 0
}
```

It works fine for me in swift